# Java ListSelectionListener double change value

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jlist

I have Java class with JList and ListSelectionListener:

```
final JList myList = new JList();

// ...

myList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {  
                System.out.println("selected");
            }
});
```

but output is

```
selected
selected
```

How should I change my code, that output should be one `selected`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
         if(e.getValueIsAdjusting())
      {
          System.out.println("Selected");  
      }
```

Comment: However when you go through the list with the up and down arrows this breaks. So in that case use 

    if(!e.getValueIsAdjusting()){
        System.out.println("Selected");
    }

Other than that this works quite well.

Comment: Chris is right, this should have a `!` in front of the `e.getValueIsAdjusting()`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [getValueIsAdjusting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html#getValueIsAdjusting%28%29).

> Returns whether or not this is one in
>   a series of multiple events, where
>   changes are still being made

Only print "selected" when this method returns false.

Comment: Although the other answers were in the right path this one should be marked as the best since getValuesAdjusting() will return false upon the last event.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to refer to:

`getValueIsAdjusting()` on the `ListSelectionEvent.`  From the API: *Returns whether or not this is one in a series of multiple events, where changes are still being made.*